# VSCode extension works in development, but not after packaging into VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-code, vsix

I have authored a VSCode extension [vscode-typer](https://github.com/domesticmouse/vscode-typer) that auto-magically live types code. Great for development demonstrations.

Problem is, while it works in development mode (I have the extension open in VSCode and I use run extension to bring up a test VSCode), however, if I use `vsce` to make a VSIX file, and then install said VSIX extension, when attempting to use my extension I see the following error: `command 'extension.devFestResetMain' not found`

I feel like I am missing a magic incantation somewhere...

Reproduction steps: [vscode-typer/issues/1](https://github.com/domesticmouse/vscode-typer/issues/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was confusing development time dependencies for run time dependencies.

Comment: Can you describe what you did to fix this?

Comment: Too long ago to remember in detail, but the tl;dr is that I had misconfigured dependencies. I suspect I was depending on a dev dependency at run time.

Comment: I had the same issue.